# how to restore the files from a version in gcloud

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I was working on a project in gcloud a few months ago using the cloud shell terminal and file editor.  Now, when I login I can no longer see the files (phython, .png, etc) but the project is still running.  I'd like to continue working on the project but it's unclear how to restore the artifacts from a deployed version back into cloudshell and the cloudshell editor.  Any tips?

Comment: To confirm, your source files were ['recycled'](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#persistent_disk_storage) by Google through inactivity of Cloud Shell? When you say "the project is still running", do you mean that you deployed it to another Google Cloud service (i.e. App Engine, Cloud Run)? Which service?

Answer (score 1):

There are some [Usage Limits](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits) to keep in mind when using the Cloud Shell:

> - **Cloud Shell inactivity**: If you do not access Cloud Shell for 120 days, your home disk will be deleted. You will receive an email notification before its deletion and simply starting a session will prevent its removal. Please consider a different solution on Google Cloud storage for sensitive data you wish to store long term.

This answers your question. Instead of using the Cloud Shell, you can [install the gCloudSDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) on your computer, in this way, all the changes you make will be there even if you don't use them for a long time.